# how to generate auth log on centos 6.7

Tags: centos, logging

I discovered that there is no auth.log on our server Centos 6.7 Linux 3.14.
I tried `service rsyslog restart` but it is not working
what is the right way to do it in Centos?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `auth.log` on CentOS because that name is a Debian-ism.

You will find logs relating to user authentication in `/var/log/secure`.